# Slides count/total with twig

Tags: wordpress, twig, fullpage.js

I use fullpage.js to create a gallery.

I would like to use it with Wordpress and Timber (TWIG). I must create loops.

I need to add an attribute in my slide's div. But I need to have two count with TWIG.

First the total of slides (data-maxslides) and after each slide must be incremented (data-currentslide).

Can I have some help please ?

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
      <div class="slide slide0">
              <div class="image-container firstslide" data-type="project" data-currentslide="1" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="http://image.com" class="image portrait">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide1">
              <div class="image-container secondslide" data-type="project" data-currentslide="2" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="http://image.com" class="image portrait">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="3" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="http://image.com" class="image portrait">
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section" id="section2">
      <div class="slide slide0">
              <div class="image-container firstslide" data-type="project" data-currentslide="1" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="http://image.com" class="image portrait">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide1">
              <div class="image-container secondslide" data-type="project" data-currentslide="2" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="http://image.com" class="image portrait">
              </div>
      </div>
      <div class="slide slide2">
              <div class="image-container" data-type="project" data-currentslide="3" data-maxslides="3"  data-title="DEMO" data-project="Sweater Collection (Hamburg, 2017)">
                  <img src="http://image.com" class="image portrait">
              </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The get the current index you can use `loop.index` or `loop.index0`, the latter starts with `0`. To get the count of a collection you can use `length`,

An example would be,

```
{% for section in sections %}
<div class="section" id="section{{ loop.index }}">
      {% for slide in slides[section.getId()] %}
      <div class="slide slide{{ loop.index0 }}">
              <div class="image-container {{ image.getClass() }}" data-type="project" data-currentslide="{{ loop.index }}" data-maxslides="{{ slides[section.getId()] | length }}"  data-title="{{ image.getTitle() }}" data-project="{{ image.getProject() }}">
                  <img src="{{ image.getSource() }}" class="image portrait">
              </div>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you ! The section loop work fine but I don't have my slide inside. I would like to create a slide for each image in each section. For that I created a repeater field wit ACF

Comment: No worries, was just an example on how to use it though :)